# Can not kill job gracefully in spark standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

There is a problem with killing streaming jobs gracefully in spark 2.1.0 with enabled spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown
I've tested killing spark jobs in many ways and I got some conclusions.

1. With command spark-submit --master spark:// --kill driver-id 

   It kills job almost immediately - not gracefully
2. With api curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/kill/driverId 

    The same like in 1. (I looked at the spark-submit code and it seems like this tool calls just REST endpoint)
3. With unix kill driver-process

    It doesn't kill the job at all (driver is immediately restarted)

Then I noticed that I'd used param: --supervise so I repeated these all tests without this flag. It turned out that 1. and 2. methods worked in the same way like before but 3. method worked like I assumed. This means, calling kill driver-process job - spark digests all messages from kafka which left and than turns down job gracefully. It is of course some solution but quite inconvenient since I must track machine with driver instead of using simple spark REST endpoint. The second downside is that I can not use flag "supervise" so whenever node with spark driver fails than job stops.

Is anybody able to explain me why there are so many issues regarding this case and why 1 and 2 methods work in different way than 3. killing.